# Ipad/ Iphone/ mac email

Tags: gmail

I configured gmail account on my IPad , Iphone and Mac. Many a times, some mails get missed in one of the system either ipad, iphone or mac. WHy????

What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I find [configuring GMail over exchange (Google Sync)](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740) works really well.

That's all I can recommend!